# Linux permissions sudoers file

Tags: linux

Is there other file like /etc/sudoers where I assign sudo permissions to the users or groups that I have created?. I have this server that has a user that is not root but when I look at sudoers file there is nothing there saying that this user can do sudo, so I'm little confused about this.

I have this output from group

```
$ more /etc/group
root::0:
other::1:root
bin::2:root,daemon
sys::3:root,bin,adm
adm::4:root,daemon
uucp::5:root
mail::6:root
tty::7:root,adm
lp::8:root,adm
nuucp::9:root
staff::10:
daemon::12:root
sysadmin::14:
games::20:
smmsp::25:
gdm::50:
upnp::52:
xvm::60:
netadm::65:
mysql::70:
openldap::75:
webservd::80:
postgres::90:
slocate::95:
unknown::96:
nobody::60001:
noaccess::60002:
nogroup::65534:
aiuser::61:
ftp::21:
pkg5srv::97:
oinstall::1001:
dba::502:oracle
oper::503:oracle
```

And this output from id:

```
$ id oracle
uid=100(oracle) gid=1001(oinstall)
```

Comment: And what output do you get from `sudo -l` as the oracle user?

Comment: sudo -l

User oracle may run the following commands on this host:
    (ALL) ALL

Comment: But where is this specified?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some of the more recent distributions have a default `/etc/sudoers` file that makes use of the `#include` and/or `#includedir` directives.

That allows you to build a sudo configuration from multiple files, which in many cases will simplify configuration management.

```
## Read drop-in files from /etc/sudoers.d (the # here does not mean a comment)
#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```

sudo rights for your oracle user might be set in `/etc/sudoers.d/oracle` or similar.

Comment: yes, you are right. There is a file in /etc/sudoers.d that says oracle ALL=(ALL) ALL. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The sudoers man page says

> The sudoers policy module determines a user's sudo privileges. It is the default sudo policy plugin. The policy is driven by the /etc/sudoers file or, optionally in LDAP.

So they are your choices, either in the [sudoers](http://www.sudo.ws/sudo/man/1.8.9/sudoers.man.html) file (or optionally an included file) or in [LDAP](http://www.sudo.ws/sudo/man/1.8.9/sudoers.ldap.man.html).